# Does dropping a SQL table reset its ID value?

Tags: mysql

Will the ID auto-increment value be reset if I drop (wipe) a MySQL table? And, if I delete (for example) the entry N° 535, will this entry number be filled again later?

I don't want that ID to be filled with other new entries if I wiped old data. If this is not the behavior, then what's the solution to avoid this?

Comment: Why don't you give it a try and let us know what happens?

Comment: I can't say for certain what the correct behavior is, but from my own testing, dropping an entire table resets the id auto-increment values, but deleting entries within the table does not.

Comment: Can anyone explain why my question downvoted, even if it's useful and clear?

Comment: If I had to guess, it was downvoted due to poor spelling/grammar/formatting.

Comment: Probably because you could have figured this out simply by trying it. That's my guess since I didn't down vote it so I can't say for sure.

Comment: @Welbog: Bad Welbog, no biscuit.  That's a terrible answer (okay, comment) for dbs in general.  Trying something on a DB and assuming that it will always work that way because an empirical test showed it worked once...bleh.  It's like the people that assume that naively assume that a simple select will always return rows from a DB table in the order they were entered.  Often true.  But not always, of course.

Comment: @Beska: Except the question is obviously just for MySQL. This is easily testable and probably well documented.

Comment: @Welbog: This question didn't have mysql tag when I commented...but beyond this, if it's documented, that's one thing...we could say that, and hopefully point out where.  But that's not what you said...you said just try it out.  I still maintain that that's a bit non-ideal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which DBMS are you using? MySQL does reset the auto-increment value when you TRUNCATE a table. You can use the (much slower) `DELETE FROM tablename` to avoid this.

Answer (score 1):

The auto_increment value doesn't change if you DELETE a line, but it is reseted if you do a `TRUNCATE TABLE`. And the next ID is always the current auto_increment value ("gaps" aren't filled again).
You can change the auto_increment value with `ALTER TABLE table  AUTO_INCREMENT = num`

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The solution would be to not DROP your table. Instead use DELETE FROM ...

Answer (score 0):

If you drop a table, it will be gone along with any identity seed values.